# alternate to maintaining a session for an API

Tags: android, rest, access-token, google-authentication

I am making a project in android where I have to login in users through google sign in button . Now after signing-in the user can travel between different activities and features . The Web Development way would be to give the user a cookie but in android I was thinking what if I send the google provided IdToken
attached with each api call that the user makes . This way it will be most secure at my level and I wont have to maintain a session .

any help is appreciated
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `HTTPS` for service calls
2. Use provided token as an id for user
3. For more flexibility, you can add a `refresh token` that every time
   original token expires, get a new token and refresh token.

Read more: [Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html)

Comment: should we place the tokens in header or send it in the request body ?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the API session Information by using the **Android preferences** and create a static function that you call it whenever you want.